# Add leading zeros left and right of hyphen

Tags: powerbi

I have a text column in PowerBI, with numeric digits separated by a hyphen. I need the left side to be exactly 5 digits. If it is less, then add leading zeros. The right side needs to be 4 digits. Any less, add leading zeros.

For example:

- 0002-800  -> 00002-0800
- 0001-0800 -> 00001-0800
- 12345-220 -> 12345-0220

Any help is appreciated. 
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Edit the query. Let's assume the text is in a column called "code".
2. Split the column by delimiter, using the dash as the delimiter
3. Create a new column that pads the code.1 with 0 if its length is less than 5, else use code.1
4. Create a new column that pads the code.2 with 0 if its length is less than 4, else use code.2
5. append the two helper columns with a dash in between
6. remove the code and helper columns and rename the remaining column to your liking.

Text.Length will return the length of a string, Text.PadStart() will pad text. The formula for step 3 above is

```
if Text.Length([code.1]) < 5 then 
    Text.PadStart([code.1], 5, "0")
else
    [code.1])
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with one step:

```
= Table.TransformColumns(
    Source, {"Column", each Text.Combine({
        Text.PadStart(Text.BeforeDelimiter(_, "-"),5,"0"), 
        Text.PadStart(Text.AfterDelimiter(_, "-"),4,"0")
        },"-"
    ),type text}
)
```